# Как правильно задать NameValueSeparator у TStringList?

Tags: delphi

```
sl: TStringList;
```

Передаю значение через `Edit1.Text`

```
sl.NameValueSeparator := Edit1.Text;
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'Integer'

Comment: Тип Char - один символ. `TEdit.Text` имеет тип string - строка. Поэтому вам и пишут "несовместимые типы". Попробуйте `Edit1.Text[1]`

Comment: @dr. F.I.N., Благодарю. Сработало!

Comment: _когда написал сообщение об ошибке руками, и сам в нем ошибся_